# Ansible error: The task includes an option with an undefined variable

Tags: ansible, syntax-error, runtime-error

Below is how my complete helpA.yml playbook looks like:

```
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
   - name: "Construct File Path {{ inventory_hostname }} before Deployment."
     tags: validate
     include_vars:
       file: "{{ item }}"
     with_fileglob:
        - "vars/{{ Layer }}_*.yaml"

   - name: "set_fact"
     tags: validate
     set_fact:
       fpath_APP: "{{ fpath_APP + [ BASEPATH ~ '/' ~ vars[item.split('.')[1]] ~ '/' ~ item | basename ] }}"
     when: Layer == 'APP'
     with_items:
       - "{{ Source_Filenames.split(',') }}"
     vars:
       fpath_APP: []

   - debug: var=fpath_{{ Layer }}
```

I'm getting the below syntax error running the yml.

> $ ansible-playbook /app/helpA.yml --tags  validate -e
>   "Source_Filenames=/tmp/logs/filename1.src,/tmp/logs/33211.sql,/app/Jenkins/file1.mrt
>   Layer=APP"  [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is
>   available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
>
> PLAY [localhost]
>
> ---
>
> TASK [Construct File Path localhost before Deployment.]
>   ************************************************************************************************* ok: [localhost] => (item=/app/vars/APP_BASE_vars.yaml)
>
> TASK [set_fact]
>   *************************************************************************************************************************************************************** fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option
>   with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no
>   attribute u'src'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/app/helpA.yml': line
>   12, column 6, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
>   syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n   - name:
>   \"set_fact\"\n     ^ here\n"}
>
> PLAY RECAP
>   ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************** localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0
>   failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

I'm on the latest version on of ansible and python 2.7.5

Comment: Are you able to share the contents of `/app/vars/APP_BASE_vars.yaml`? This would help to isolate the problem. Basically you are looking up the dict `vars` for a key `src` (which is your file extension), and it doesn't exist

Comment: Here are the contents [has only one line] of /app/vars/APP_BASE_vars.yaml                                                                        
                                                           BASEPATH: /app/1090/BC10.2/app/cust/01

Comment: Yep ok .. so the problem is as I stated above, but I'm not clear on what you are trying to achieve. What is your expectation for the final contents of the variable `fpath_APP`?

Comment: Rightly pointed .....Putting src variable in the vars file resolves the issue. Thank you @Matt P